# My ggplot in r is showing small intersecting bars within the graphic, how do i remove these?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the attached code and plot show my issue. I have small lines intersecting my bars in my bar graph that should not be there...any ideas on how to remove these?

[image: ggplot code]

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image, no one wants to re-type your code to start to solve your problem. And please make a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem due to assistance from another source (reddit). Thank you for your help

Turns out my rows had multiple values with the same str_detect (ie: sub_HALabuse and sub_HALdependence.) Once I created columns correcting the values, it worked. Thank you!